# App Export Compliance using the Dropbox API

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, encryption, app-store, dropbox

This question (or variations of this question) has been asked before, but as Apple's export compliance rules change relatively frequently, and no one seems to ever get a straight answer, I thought I would ask.

I write an iPhone application that uses version 0.2 of the Dropbox API.

I have emailed Apple concerning use of this specific API, and I will be sure to update this question as I learn more and hear back from Apple. In the meantime, if any developer is using the Dropbox API in their iPhone application, did you mark your application as using encryption?

**Edit:** Upon closer inspection, it looks like the file data is also transferred using SSL. Since their API is using the NSMutableURLRequest class over HTTPS though, I still can't determine whether or not this API "uses encryption." If in the App Store submission page I mark that it does include encryption, Apple then asks if I'm using greater than a 64-bit symmetric encryption key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your app uses SSL (HTTPS), then yes it does include encryption. The export compliance rules changed last year though, so you will need an Encryption Registration Number instead of a CCATS number. See [this blog post for details](http://tigelane.blogspot.com/2011/01/apple-itunes-export-restrictions-on.html).

Comment: Does it include encryption that uses an asymmetric algorithm with a key greater than 64 bits? This seems to be the deciding factor as to whether or not the form is needed.

Comment: As far as I know, the DropBox API uses 256-bit SSL (I may be wrong, but in that case it would still be a minimum of 128 bits).

Comment: Yea, I heard back from the Dropbox folks as well. ERN is definitely required. What a pain!

Comment: Getting an ERN shouldn't take more than 2 weeks though, although having to report every year is a little annoying.

Comment: Yea, I actually obtained my ERN today. Going to submit an update to Apple soon!

Comment: I think it is easier and less hassle than CCATS that you had to do before.

Answer (score 3):

As it happens I'm working on this right now on a related project.

The Apple position is clarified in the FAQ in iTunesConnect; (my bold)

> If **your App** contains, uses or
>   **accesses** standard cryptography for purposes other than those listed in
>   questions 2-4, you need to submit for
>   an ERN authorization. **Examples of
>   standard encryption are: AES, SSL,
>   https.**
>
> This authorization requires that you
>   submit an annual report to two U.S.
>   Government agencies with information
>   about your App every January.

It's a pain in the neck, but that is the law if you want to be fully compliant. I'd love to hear that I'm wrong though!

PS. You could always ask for a direct opinion from the Government department concerned here;

http://www.bis.doc.gov/forms/rpdform.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also call the Bureau of Industry and Security help desk at 202-482-0707 or read the web site at http://www.bis.doc.gov/encryption for more information.

Discussing your question with a live person is probably going to be better than filling out the online form and waiting for a response.